# Emailing HTML page containing images

Tags: html, image

I'm a student studying a Certificate in Web Development.

I've written a webpage in HTML which contains 2 images which are displaying fine however when I copy the folder containing the files into a ZIP file (so I can email it) the images no longer show when the webpage is opened from the ZIP file.  The code for displaying the image is:

```
<img src="logo.jpg" height="150" alt="Logo for Club Palmy"/>
```

And the image is definitely in the folder I've copied and pasted into the ZIP file

Comment: It depends how did you zip folder and how did you extracted zip to view html in browser. i

Answer (score 0):

**Why won't it work?**

Yes it won't work because what really happens when you open something directly from a zip is that it extracts that "specific" file to a temporary location first and then opens the extracted file. 
Winrar extracts the archives to
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp (Windows)
by default.
So what really is happening is that your html document exists but your images don't exist in the same directory i.e. the path mentioned above.

**What you should do?**

Extract all the files and not try opening them directly from the zip.